# Error when running executable jar in command line in Intellij IDE

Tags: java

Everything works fine when running via **Intellij IDE** in *Run mode and Debug mode*. However, when run from command line the executable jar, 
I get the following:
 `NoSuchMethodError for io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.newAtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.` 

What could cause this and what to do about it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you build your executable jar?  Did you use a build tool?

Comment: Yes, I used Intellij, which provides an option for building an executable Jar.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is caused by incorrect version of netty being packed or available at runtime. If the version is different from what is used when you run it in your IDE it may result in this error or may work incorrectly.
Make sure that you are packaging all required libraries and correct versions of them too.
P.S. Your system JRE is not necessarily the same as your IDE's JRE

Comment: Yeah, you might have something here. So we are mid-switch to Java 8 and this project is something of a mix between Java 7 and 8, though they should be the same for this package. This at least gives me a direction to go in with troubleshooting.  Thanks much!!

Comment: One additional suggestion: simply open your netty.jar file and see if it has the path and file io/netty/util/internal/PlatformDependent, newAtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.class.  A .jar file is just a .zip file: you can open it and examine the contents with WinZip or 7-Zip; or rename it to a .zip extension and examine it with Windows Explorer.